# How to configure Postfix to allow one IP to relay to any destination?

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta, relay

I have a local Postfix which is used to relay emails from local network to local domain users.

I should now allow one sender IP address to be able to relay to any destination email domain.

Current configuration looks like:

main.cf

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination<br>
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/allowed_senders, reject
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/allowed_recipients, reject
mynetworks = 10.10.0.0/16
relayhost = mydomain.mail.protection.outlook.com:25
```

allowed_senders

```
mydomain.com       OK
```

allowed_recipients

```
mydomain.com       OK
```

How can I whitelist one sender IP address to send to any domain but keep the other restrictions in place?